# Retrieve a redirected URL using WinHttp in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, winhttp

Im looking to build a sub that can retrieve a redirected URL and place it in a cell. I have a range of cells containing numbers that complete a URL. This link is opened using WinHTTP and the file is then saved in PDF format. The returned page is a redirect and I need to pull the URL to isolate important information each time this is opened. I have seen functions that apparantly are capable of doing this but havent been able to get them to work and I have little experience with WinHTTP. Ive tried to make sense of the published functions but have been unable to so far. I would prefer to keep it as a sub over function if possible.
Any help would be appreciated
Below is the closest thing I could find that may suit my requirements but am having trouble running it as a sub.

```
Public Function testRedirect(oCell As Range) As String

 testRedirect = "not redirected"

 strURL = oCell.Hyperlinks(1).Address

 WinHttpRequestOption_EnableRedirects = 6

 Set oWinHttp = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
 oWinHttp.Option(WinHttpRequestOption_EnableRedirects) = False

 oWinHttp.Open "HEAD", strURL, False
 oWinHttp.send ""

 If oWinHttp.Status = 301 Then
  strResponseHeaders = oWinHttp.getAllResponseHeaders()
  For Each strResponseHeader In Split(strResponseHeaders, Chr(10))
   If Left(strResponseHeader, 9) = "Location:" Then
    testRedirect = "redirected to " & strResponseHeader
   End If
  Next
 End If

End Function
```

The following code is what Im using to request the files and save them which works well but needs the above fitted in there somewhere. Please excuse the formatting. Ive only gotten to the stage where it works and have not had time to polish it. There may also be un needed variables etc.

```
Sub Printdrawings()


Dim WB As Workbook
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim ROWS As Long
Dim IE As Object
Dim LINKS As Variant
Dim LINK As Variant
Dim RNG As Range
Dim URL As String
Dim CLL As Range

Dim FileNum As Long
Dim FileData() As Byte
Dim MyFile As String
Dim WHTTP As Object
Dim FileName As String


Set WB = ThisWorkbook
Set WS = WB.Sheets("Sheet1")

'Calculates the amount of used rows in column A
ROWS = WS.Cells(WS.ROWS.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Debug.Print ROWS

'Sets a range based on the variable counted occupied rows from above
Set RNG = WS.Range("A1:A" & ROWS)

    
   For Each CLL In RNG
    
    On Error Resume Next
        Set WHTTP = CreateObject("WinHTTP.WinHTTPrequest.5")
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            Set WHTTP = CreateObject("WinHTTP.WinHTTPrequest.5.1")
        End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    
    
    MyFile = "http://URLBODY" & CLL
    
    WHTTP.Open "GET", MyFile, False
    WHTTP.Send
    FileData = WHTTP.ResponseBody
    Set WHTTP = Nothing
    
    If Dir("C:\MyDownloads", vbDirectory) = Empty Then MkDir "C:\MyDownloads"
    
    FileName = Right(MyFile, 12)
    Debug.Print FileName
    FileNum = FreeFile
    Open "C:\MyDownloads\" & FileName & ".pdf" For Binary Access Write As #FileNum
        Put #FileNum, 1, FileData
    Close #FileNum
    
    Next CLL
    
    
    MsgBox "Open the folder [ C:\MyDownloads ] for the downloaded file..."


End Sub
```

Comment: Is there an example we can test with? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43058308/6241235) looks like a starter for 10 or  [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5023d3d7-3a91-47b5-b429-1a6c6c20ab7f/catch-redirect-url?forum=xmlandnetfx) same approach

Comment: ill try to find something but its actually on the servers of my company, accessing electrical drawings. Im able to put in a url with the number and it returns a pdf with with a redirected url. Its not continuous redirecting like ad servers elsewhere so Im thinking a similar effect might be accessing  google outside of your country and it automatically redirecting you back to your location?

Comment: Is there a reason for needing to collect this redirect url? Is it important enough for the company to provide it in the response/documentation?

Comment: `CLL.Offset(0,1).Value = testRedirect(CLL)` would check each cell and put the result in the next column to the right.

Comment: Yeah in a perfect world there would be a system in place for this but there isnt one for some reason and something like this bridges the gap. The reason for collecting the redirected URL is because it shows the revision number for the document. The request URL only requires the drawing number and it retrieves the latest revision, which is displayed in the redirected URL. An automated way of displaying the last downloaded revision and checking to see if a newer version exists would save hundreds of hours each time. It also enables checks to happen more often.

Comment: Thanks Tim. Ill give that a go and see what happens.

Comment: Hi Tim,
I havent been able to get that to work. Is there a reference im missing?
Cheers

Comment: I have been doing a bit more research and i dont think i need to worry about the whole redirects thing. Is there a way using winhttp, to get the source url at all. I feel like this is absolutely a basic function of this, but cant seem to find any way to make it happen. I sort of got it to work with a netflix redirect using response headers but it changes from site to site and it doent work for my application.